# Maven - Generate .genmodel and sources from .ecore

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, emf, ecore

I'm currently trying to build my project with Maven.
The problem arises with EMF when I try to generate the sources.

I did a lot of research on how to trigger the build process so that the sources are generated when already the .genmodel is available.
However, I didn't find any reference of how to do that with Maven.
Apparently, there is a maven-plugin, namely [maven-emfgen-plugin](http://mapasuta.sourceforge.net/maven/site/maven-emfgen-plugin/usage.html) but it seems outdated.
When I try the snipped provided at this site, what I get is a failure that tells me that my eclipse version is no longer supported.
I added the exact error message below.

Now my exact questions are:

1. How do I generate sources from a .genmodel with Maven
2. How do I generate .genmodel from .ecore with Maven

Regards,
Lars

> Error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.sf.mapasuta.build.maven.plugins:maven-emfgen-plugin:1.1:genmodel
>   (generate-mm-sources) on project org.emoflon.ibex.tgg.editor: Eclipse
>   version 4.6.2 not yet supported. -> [Help 1]